# How to prevent resizing of a SWT combo?

Tags: java, combobox, swt

When I call `setItems(String[])` the combo box will become wider to fit the length of the new items.

How to make it not resizable no matter how wide the new items are?

I've tried it with `ControlListener`. I saved the initial size of the combo and set it each time the `controlResized()` was called. As the result the combo width remains constant but the rest of the UI looks ugly when I resize it. It is a wizard. I'm using GridLayout

Comment: What Layout are you using?

Comment: @greg-449 GridLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `GridLayout` for your layout you can specify a `widthHint` in the layout data for the combo.

```
GridData data = new GridData(....);

data.widthHint = 100;

combo.setLayoutData(data);
```

If this is in a dialog you can use `convertWidthInCharsToPixels(chars)` to specify a width in characters rather than pixel. `Dialog` also has a static version of this method you can use outside of a dialog.